# Returning rows in a table where a value in a column occurs more than once

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables person and orderr, and want to return the rows from person when a person has more than one order in the orderr table, using the personID.

```
SELECT person.* FROM person JOIN orderr ON person.personID = orderr.personID HAVING COUNT(orderr.personID) > 1;
```

The above seems to print first row in the table.

Here is the data from the orderr table :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to express this as a `join` and aggregation:

```
SELECT person.*
FROM person JOIN
     orderr
     ON person.personID = orderr.personID 
GROUP by person.personID
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: I have three people who have more than one order, but this only returns 2 of them.

Comment: @JohnCollins . . . This is a correct query (as are the other answers) based on your descdription.  Can you edit your question and include the data with the multiple orders?

Answer (score 0):

To get just personID:

```
select personID
from orderr 
group by personID
having COUNT(*) > 1
```

or to get all person fields:

```
select *
from person
where personID in (
    select personID
    from orderr 
    group by personID
    having COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: This also seems to only return two, is the ; meant to be before the bracket ?